# Cultivation manga where the main character regresses into his earlier self

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

The manga has to do with cultivation because the main character (a son I believe) was amazing but then he got crippled, not in a literal sense, but like his meridians were destroyed. Then he was frowned upon by everyone. Next he was put inside a cage hanging in the middle of town I think and people hate him but what we don't see is that while he was sitting there he already had done all this before.

He regress/reincarnates into his younger self and knows what to do from now on. At midnight he was going to be assassinated but he killed the people trying to kill him because during his first life a master had broken him out and took care of him but now it was himself that did the killing because he returned to his younger self. Then he meets some lady who takes him to his home and proves to everyone that he is strong again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ***[I Return from the Heavens and Worlds](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/xxw5a8f/i-return-from-the-heavens-and-worlds)***.

> Sitting in the prison for three years. Li Xiantian is back! He carries the seven strongest bloodlines of the heavens, twelve peak master skills, thirty-six sets of ten thousand realm supreme exercises, seventy-two mysterious and strongest skills, and one hundred and eight laws of chaos. But with his current strength, the bloodline spirit beast he summoned is a pig?

Comment: cool thanks dude your a life saver

Comment: Although the OP has accepted the answer, you could make it a far better answer if you provided some details and documentation; even tho the OPs need has been met, the more details you include, the more is there for another use to find when searching for their answer.